# Typesense server hangs on sort_by by int and bool fields

Tags: typesense

I am running Typesense server, which works fine. However, it hangs when I try to use `sort_by` parameter on `int` or `bool` fields. When I use field of type `string`, it instantly returns sorted results.

Any idea why would Typesense hang on `int` or `bool` fields ? There is nothing in log output.

Thank you for any help or hints.

EDIT: set-up I am using:

```
$productSchema = [   'name' => 'products',   'fields' => [
    ['name' => 'name', 'type' => 'string', 'sort' => true],
    ['name' => 'seo_url', 'type' => 'string'],
    ['name' => 'short_description', 'type' => 'string'],
    ['name' => 'long_description', 'type' => 'string'],
    ['name' => 'product_number', 'type' => 'string'],
    ['name' => 'attributes', 'type' => 'string'],
    ['name' => 'on_stock', 'type' => 'bool', 'optional' => true, 'index' => false, 'sort' => true],
    ['name' => 'last_purchase', 'type' => 'int32', 'optional' => true, 'index' => false, 'sort' => true],
    ['name' => 'attributes_ids', 'type' => 'int32[]', 'index' => false, 'optional' => true],
    ['name' => 'category', 'type' => 'string'],
    ['name' => 'category_ids', 'type' => 'int32[]', 'index' => false, 'optional' => true],
    ['name' => 'image_url', 'type' => 'string', 'index' => false, 'optional' => true],
    ['name' => 'price_vat', 'type' => 'float', 'index' => false, 'optional' => true, 'sort' => true]   ] ];
```

And search query:

```
curl -H "X-TYPESENSE-API-KEY: key" "http://localhost:8108/collections/products/documents/search?q=jednoro&query_by=name&sort_by=price_vat:asc"
```

And here is example of indexed documents.

```
{"facet_counts":[],"found":66,"hits":[{"document":{"attributes":"Jednorožec, bavlna / elastan, Žlutá, Růžová, Zelená, Holčičí vzor","attributes_ids":[71,3,13,15,18,32],"category":"Potisk úplety","category_ids":[8],"id":"3726","image_url":"https://example.com/foto/51/8173X250X233~dxndYq.jpg","last_purchase":1573686000,"long_description":"<p>&Uacute;plet s poh&aacute;dkov&yacute;mi jednorožci na &uacute;žasn&eacute;m duhov&eacute;m podkladu vol&aacute; po u&scaron;it&iacute; &scaron;atů pro mal&eacute; princezny. Pořiďte sv&eacute; holčičce origin&aacute;ln&iacute; kousek do &scaron;atn&iacute;ku, bude nad&scaron;en&aacute;! A vy s n&iacute;.:-)</p>\r\n<p>&Uacute;plet je pružn&yacute; ve směru osnovy i &uacute;tku, vhodn&yacute;&nbsp;na každodenn&iacute; no&scaron;en&iacute;.</p>\r\n<p><strong>Karmelie doporučuje na &scaron;it&iacute;:</strong>&nbsp;Vhodn&yacute; na v&yacute;robu triček, trik s dlouh&yacute;m ruk&aacute;vem,&nbsp;&scaron;atiček, suk&yacute;nek. Využ&iacute;t jej můžete i na leg&iacute;ny.&nbsp;Dopřejte va&scaron;&iacute;&nbsp;mysli&nbsp;popustit uzdu sv&eacute; fantazie!</p>\r\n<p>NEZAPOMEŇTE: &Uacute;plet před&nbsp;&scaron;it&iacute;m vysr&aacute;žet.<br /><br />Ostatn&iacute;: barvy nemus&iacute; plně odpov&iacute;dat skutečnosti, odchylky jsou způsobeny nespr&aacute;vnou kalibrac&iacute; monitoru.</p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>","name":"Úplet barevní jednorožci na duhovém podkladu","on_stock":false,"price_vat":335,"product_number":"UPS009","reserved_amount":"0.00","seo_url":"uplet-barevni-jednorozci-na-duhovem-podkladu","short_description":"Šířka: 150–155 cm Gramáž: 210 - 215 g/m² Složení: 95% bavlna, 5% elastan. Certifikát pro děti do 3 let.","warehouse_amount":"0.00"},"highlights":[{"field":"name","matched_tokens":["jednoro"],"snippet":"Úplet barevní <mark>jednoro</mark>žci na duhovém podkladu"}],"text_match":72341261125681153},{"document":{"attributes":"Jednorožec, Červená, Holčičí vzor, bavlna / elastan","attributes_ids":[71,16,32,3],"category":"Potisk úplety","category_ids":[8],"id":"3210","image_url":"https://example.com/foto/66/30769X250X233~cHZGNa.jpeg","last_purchase":1568757600,"long_description":"<p><strong>Karmelie doporučuje na &scaron;it&iacute;:&nbsp;</strong></p>\r\n<p>Nejraději z něj &scaron;vadlenky &scaron;ij&iacute;&nbsp;trička.&nbsp;D&aacute;le se hod&iacute; na trika s dlouh&yacute;m ruk&aacute;vem, tuniky. Využ&iacute;t ho lze i na aplikaci. Ide&aacute;ln&iacute; do kombinace k jednobarevn&yacute;m &uacute;pletům v barvě podkladu či vzoru, panelům.Podle vkusu tak&eacute; k ostatn&iacute;m designov&yacute;m &uacute;pletům z na&scaron;&iacute; nab&iacute;dky.</p>\r\n<p>NEZAPOMEŇTE:<br />&Uacute;plet před &scaron;it&iacute;m vysr&aacute;žet.</p>\r\n<p>Ostatn&iacute;: barvy nemus&iacute; plně odpov&iacute;dat skutečnosti, odchylky jsou způsobeny nespr&aacute;vnou kalibrac&iacute; monitoru.</p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>","name":"Úplet potisk digitální jednorožci na bordó","on_stock":true,"price_vat":310,"product_number":"UPS001","reserved_amount":"0.00","seo_url":"uplet-potisk-digitalni-jednorozci-na-bordo","short_description":"Šířka: 150 cm. Gramáž: 210 g/m². Složení: 95% bavlna, 5% elastan. Certifikát pro děti do 3 let.","warehouse_amount":"6.30"},"highlights":[{"field":"name","matched_tokens":["jednoro"],"snippet":"Úplet potisk digitální <mark>jednoro</mark>žci na bordó"}],"text_match":72341261125681153},{"document":{"attributes":"Jednorožec, Černá, Holčičí vzor, bavlna / elastan","attributes_ids":[71,20,32,3],"category":"Potisk úplety","category_ids":[8],"id":"7981","image_url":"https://example.com/foto/20/24067X250X233~e1IF84.jpg","last_purchase":1619215200,"long_description":"<div class=\"specs-row\">Jednorožci se mezi holčičkami tě&scaron;&iacute; oblibě už hodně roků, proto se s nimi ponořte do kouzeln&eacute;ho světa pln&eacute;ho těchto b&aacute;jn&yacute;ch tvorů.:-)&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div class=\"specs-row\">&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div class=\"specs-row\"><strong>Karmelie doporučuje na &scaron;it&iacute;:&nbsp;</strong></div>\r\n<p>Vhodn&yacute; na v&yacute;robu triček, trik s dlouh&yacute;m ruk&aacute;vem, suk&yacute;nek, &scaron;atiček a dal&scaron;&iacute;ho oblečen&iacute;. Využ&iacute;t jej můžete i na jarn&iacute; čepice, tunely a &scaron;&aacute;tko&scaron;&aacute;ly. Skvěle se bude hodit jako doplňuj&iacute;c&iacute; materi&aacute;l k mikině na kapsy, nebo vnitřn&iacute; č&aacute;st kapuce.:-)</p>\r\n<p>Rada pro zač&aacute;tečn&iacute;ka:<br />Při &scaron;it&iacute; &uacute;pletů si nandejte do stroje jehlu JERSEY, kter&aacute; je určena pro &scaron;it&iacute; pružn&yacute;ch l&aacute;tek. Tyto jehly jsou určen&eacute; pro &uacute;plety a maj&iacute; zakulacenou &scaron;pičku. Nepo&scaron;kod&iacute; tak očka pleteniny a snadno vklouzne mezi ně. U použit&iacute; obyčejn&eacute; jehly hroz&iacute; naru&scaron;en&iacute; &uacute;pletu, což by vedlo s každ&yacute;m pran&iacute;m a no&scaron;en&iacute;m ke zvět&scaron;uj&iacute;c&iacute; se d&iacute;rce.</p>\r\n<p>NEZAPOMEŇTE:<br />&Uacute;plet před pran&iacute;m vysr&aacute;žet.</p>\r\n<p>Ostatn&iacute;: barvy nemus&iacute; plně odpov&iacute;dat skutečnosti, odchylky jsou způsobeny nespr&aacute;vnou kalibrac&iacute; monitoru.</p>","name":"Úplet potisk jednorožci mezi lístečky na černé","on_stock":true,"price_vat":315,"product_number":"UPS207","reserved_amount":"0.00","seo_url":"uplet-potisk-jednorozci-mezi-listecky-na-cerne","short_description":"Šířka: 160 cm Gramáž: 200 g/m² Složení: 95% bavlna, 5% elastan. Certifikát pro děti do 3 let.","warehouse_amount":"22.10"},"highlights":[{"field":"name","matched_tokens":["jednoro"],"snippet":"Úplet potisk <mark>jednoro</mark>žci mezi lístečky na černé"}],"text_match":72341261125681153},{"document":{"attributes":"Jednorožec, Fialová, Holčičí vzor, bavlna / elastan","attributes_ids":[71,21,32,3],"category":"Potisk úplety","category_ids":[8],"id":"7982","image_url":"https://example.com/foto/38/24068X250X233~9huTQ.jpg","last_purchase":1619215200,"long_description":"<div class=\"specs-row\">Jednorožci se mezi holčičkami tě&scaron;&iacute; oblibě už hodně roků, proto se s nimi ponořte do kouzeln&eacute;ho světa pln&eacute;ho těchto b&aacute;jn&yacute;ch tvorů.:-)&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div class=\"specs-row\">&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div class=\"specs-row\"><strong>Karmelie doporučuje na &scaron;it&iacute;:&nbsp;</strong></div>\r\n<p>Vhodn&yacute; na v&yacute;robu triček, trik s dlouh&yacute;m ruk&aacute;vem, suk&yacute;nek, &scaron;atiček a dal&scaron;&iacute;ho oblečen&iacute;. Využ&iacute;t jej můžete i na jarn&iacute; čepice, tunely a &scaron;&aacute;tko&scaron;&aacute;ly. Skvěle se bude hodit jako doplňuj&iacute;c&iacute; materi&aacute;l k mikině na kapsy, nebo vnitřn&iacute; č&aacute;st kapuce.:-)</p>\r\n<p>Rada pro zač&aacute;tečn&iacute;ka:<br />Při &scaron;it&iacute; &uacute;pletů si nandejte do stroje jehlu JERSEY, kter&aacute; je určena pro &scaron;it&iacute; pružn&yacute;ch l&aacute;tek. Tyto jehly jsou určen&eacute; pro &uacute;plety a maj&iacute; zakulacenou &scaron;pičku. Nepo&scaron;kod&iacute; tak očka pleteniny a snadno vklouzne mezi ně. U použit&iacute; obyčejn&eacute; jehly hroz&iacute; naru&scaron;en&iacute; &uacute;pletu, což by vedlo s každ&yacute;m pran&iacute;m a no&scaron;en&iacute;m ke zvět&scaron;uj&iacute;c&iacute; se d&iacute;rce.</p>\r\n<p>NEZAPOMEŇTE:<br />&Uacute;plet před pran&iacute;m vysr&aacute;žet.</p>\r\n<p>Ostatn&iacute;: barvy nemus&iacute; plně odpov&iacute;dat skutečnosti, odchylky jsou způsobeny nespr&aacute;vnou kalibrac&iacute; monitoru.</p>","name":"Úplet potisk jednorožci mezi lístečky na fialové","on_stock":true,"price_vat":315,"product_number":"UPS208","reserved_amount":"0.00","seo_url":"uplet-potisk-jednorozci-mezi-listecky-na-fialove","short_description":"Šířka: 160 cm Gramáž: 200 g/m² Složení: 95% bavlna, 5% elastan. Certifikát pro děti do 3 let.","warehouse_amount":"18.40"},"highlights":[{"field":"name","matched_tokens":["jednoro"],"snippet":"Úplet potisk <mark>jednoro</mark>žci mezi lístečky na fialové"}],"text_match":72341261125681153}}
```

Comment: Could you post the collection schema, some sample documents and the full search query that causes this issue?

Comment: @ErJab Thanks for your help. I've added examples which I use. I don't know if it's relevant, but there is around 10 000 documents in this collection. But I suppose that it's not any significant amount and Typesense should handle it just fine, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`price_vat` is set to `'index' => false` in the schema, so it can't be used for sorting - only indexed fields can be used for sorting / filtering / searching. So if you change `price_vat` to `'index' => true` this should work as expected.

Side note: There is a missing validation in Typesense which is causing it to hang instead of reporting an error in this case. There's now an open issue to fix this in an upcoming RC.